# One single MySQL database for many web2py applications

Tags: python, web2py

I have 3 apps under my web2py framework. Can I use one single MySQL database for all of them (by prefixing tables) so users just need only one single registration to access those 3 apps? I fail on my attempts. Or any other solutions? Thanks so much.

Comment: Fail on your "attempts"? You may need to elaborate on that.

Comment: Hello. It fails as soon as I set all 3 DALs of my app with the same database. It works okay if the database used by just one app. Thanks.

Comment: and if i traceback, it says InternalError: (1050, u"Table 'auth_user' already exists"). sure it already exists because created by the first app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If multiple apps share the same database table, all but one of the apps must define that table with `migrate=False` to prevent migration attempts. Note, `Auth.define_tables()` also takes a `migrate` argument, so to turn off migrations specifically for the `Auth` tables, you can do:

```
auth.define_tables(migrate=False)
```

You can also turn off migrations for an entire database connection within an application with:

```
db = DAL(..., migrate_enabled=False)
```

See [here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#Cooperation) for more about inter-app cooperation.

Comment: But I'm still lost about how one registration could apply to all apps?

Comment: You might also consider setting up a [Central Authentication Service](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/08#Central-Authentication-Service), and let one of the apps be the provider, and the others consumers.

Comment: Thanks again for the directions, Anthony. CAS is exactly what I need right now.