# Clarification on web2py apps sharing a single database

Tags: sqlite, web2py, shared

Sorry, I'm a little unclear on the [web2py manual explanation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#Migrations).

as an example, given app1 and app2

I want to have app2 share the database I have built in app1

So do I change the app2/models/db.py file to show: db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite',migrate='false')  ?

and include all other myModel.py files in app2/models directory as well?

if the database is in app1/databases/ how does app2 know how to find the correct database file?

[This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033307/one-single-mysql-database-for-many-web2py-applications) begins to answer the question but I'm still unclear on how to define where the shared database lives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, `DAL(..., migrate=False)` just sets the default value of `migrate` for each table -- it will not have any effect on the migration status of tables whose `define_table()` calls include their own explicit `migrate` argument. If you want to completely disable migrations for an entire db connection (regardless of the individual `define_table()` calls), instead use:

```
DAL(..., migrate_enabled=False)
```

Also, to share model definitions between applications, rather than simply copying the model files, you could put the definitions in functions or classes within modules and then import the modules. Another option is to use [auto_import](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#Using-DAL-without-define-tables):

```
DAL(..., auto_import=True)
```

Note, `auto_import` will import the field names and types, but it will not include DAL-specific attributes, such as validators and defaults, so its usage is somewhat limited.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this right now but the answer should be:

- you can override the folder in the DAL:

  So both apps should point to the same file.

  (see the [docs](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#Using-DAL-without-define-tables) and this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/web2py/vzMWpOWPC68)).

.

```
db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite',folder='path/to/app/databases')
```

- yes, should need the model files in both apps too, otherwise the apps won't know how to access the db.